# How do I speed up a sql query searching from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's an example, so I have table `user` and table `city`, they're like this:

`user` columns are (user_id, city_id, timestamp) **[user_id and city_id are unique]**

`city` columns are (city_name, city_id) **[city_id is unique]**

And I want to get user count in a given date from certain city, so basically I did it like this:

```
select city_id, city_name, 
    (select count(user.user_id) 
     from user, city 
     where DATE_FORMAT(user.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2017-03-07' 
     and user.city_id = ct.city_id) as user_count
from city ct 
where (city_id = 20 or city_id = 30)
```

And Result:

```
city_id, city_name, user_count
20       New York   100
30       LA         200
```

Then I realized this is way slower than searching directly for

```
select count(user.user_id) 
from user, city 
where DATE_FORMAT(user.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2017-03-07' 
    and user.city_id = 20
```

Why is this? Isn't `ct.city_id` in the original search already being set as either 20 or 30? How should I optimize the search and get the result in the table format I want?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on these tables?

Comment: Your second query is *not* the same as the first query.  The second query is doing a `CROSS JOIN` where the first one is doing an `INNER JOIN`.  This type of implicit `JOIN` syntax has also been deprecated for [*over 25 years*](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).  You should be using explicit `JOIN`s.  They are much cleaner, much clearer, and much easier to convert to `OUTER JOIN`s if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could improve your query avoiding subselect and using an inner join and group by

```
select city_id, city_name,    count(user.user_id) 
from user
inner join city on user.city_id = city.city_id
where DATE_FORMAT(user.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2017-03-07' 
and city_id in (city_id = 20 or city_id = 30)
group by city_id, city_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I am would assume that MySQL is choosing to materialize your derived table into an internal temporary table in the first query, and does not make that choice with your second query.

> For derived tables (subqueries in the FROM clause), the optimizer has these choices:
>
> - Merge the derived table into the outer query block
> - Materialize the derived table to an internal temporary table

source: [Mysql Documentation - 8.2.2 Optimizing Subqueries, Derived Tables, and Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select city_id, city_name, count(user.user_id) as user_count
from city ct 
inner join user on user.city_id = ct.city_id
where (ct.city_id = 20 or ct.city_id = 30)
AND DATE_FORMAT(user.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2017-03-07'
```